# Simulate / Emulate a computer to test linux in

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

So I am not foreign to linux and installing different distros on my Macbook Pro, but I was wondering if there was a less painful way of setting up and testing linux. I was wondering whether there was software, sort of like VMWare, that would set up a virtual machine, but the virtual machine would simulate/emulate (not sure what the right word is) a specific computer, like the MacbookPro, and its specific hardware, such that when I installed linux in the VM, i would have to use all the proper MacbookPro drivers.

This way, I could keep a browser open while troubleshooting a linux install, as I am limited to only one computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Virtualization solutions usually provide a specific, basic set of peripherals in order to be compatible with a large number of guest operating systems; there is no provision for pick-and-choose. So, no.

Answer (score 0):

There are several.  [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) seems to have a big following.

Comment: VirtualBox will have no way of doing what the OP wants to do, VB uses their own drivers bundled with their tool package installed in the guest OS. Ignacio is correct, the answer is no, there is no solution for this in existence.